# In which cases is Arc<Mutex<T>> not the best way for sharing data across threads in Rust?

Tags: rust

From what I've learned, I should always choose `Arc<T>` for shared read access across threads and `Arc<Mutex<T>>` for shared write access across threads. Are there cases where I don't want to use `Arc<T>`/`Arc<Mutex<T>>` and instead do something completely different? E.g. do something like this:

```
unsafe impl Sync for MyStruct {}
unsafe impl Send for MyStruct {}

let shared_data_for_writing = Arc::from(MyStruct::new());
```

Comment: Rust has a pretty good [primer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.5.0/book/choosing-your-guarantees.html) on this, allowing you to choose exactly what your guarantees are and what overhead will be incurred as a result.

Comment: For example, in certain scenarios, you may want to use `Arc<RwLock<T>>` rather than `Arc<Mutex<T>>`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Sharing across threads

Besides `Arc<T>`, we can share objects across threads using scoped threads, e.g. by using [`crossbeam::scope`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.7.2/crossbeam/fn.scope.html) and [`Scope::spawn`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.7.2/crossbeam/thread/struct.Scope.html#method.spawn). Scoped threads allow us to send borrowed pointers (`&'a T`) to threads spawned in a scope. The scope guarantees that the thread will terminate before the referent is dropped. Borrowed pointers have no runtime overhead compared to `Arc<T>` (`Arc<T>` takes a bit more memory and needs to maintain a reference counter using atomic instructions).

### Mutating across threads

`Mutex<T>` is the most basic general-purpose wrapper for ensuring at most one thread may mutate a value at any given time. `Mutex<T>` has one drawback: if there are many threads that only want to *read* the value in the mutex, they can't do so concurrently, even though it would be safe. [`RwLock<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) solves this by allowing multiple concurrent readers (while still ensuring a writer has exclusive access).

Atomic types such as [`AtomicUsize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicUsize.html) also allow mutation across threads, but only for small values (8, 16, 32 or 64 bits ­– some processors support atomic operations on 128-bit values, but that's not exposed in the standard library yet; see [`atomic::Atomic`](https://docs.rs/atomic/0.4.5/atomic/struct.Atomic.html) for that). For example, instead of `Arc<Mutex<usize>>`, you could use `Arc<AtomicUsize>`. Atomic types do not require locking, but they are manipulated through atomic machine instructions. The set of atomic instructions is a bit different from the set of non-atomic instructions, so switching from a non-atomic type to an atomic type might not always be a "drop-in replacement".